# Duplicate local variable in JSP in RAD

Tags: jsp, duplicates, rad

I get a "Duplicate Local Variable" error in JSP after build in RAD. I have same variable names inside scriptlet tags different logic:present / logic iterate tags. 
Sample code.

`<logic:present> 
<%
  int var1 = 5;
%>
</logic:present>
...................
<logic:present> 
<%
  int var1 = 5;
%>
</logic:present>` 

  Since the variable are in different scope, they are not duplicates. Are the variables in the same scope ? If not, is it some compilation / validation problem in RAD ? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are indeed in the same scope they wouldn't if it were like this for example:

```
<logic:present> 
  <% {int var1 = 5; }%>
 </logic:present>
 ................... 
<logic:present> 
  <% int var1 = 5; %>
 </logic:present>
```

In the end everything will be translated into one method, thats why your code assistent generates you an error. Anyway as BalusC said it is not recommended to use scriptlets.

Answer (score 1):

RAD is right. You're using *scriptlets* (those old fashioned `<% %>` things which should be [avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)) instead of taglibs (for example `<prefix:name>`) to work with server side data. The *scriptlets* doesn't run in the same scope as those taglibs as you seem to expect. **All** *scriptlets* declared by `<% %>` share the **same** local scope. Get rid of them and replace them by the appropriate taglibs. Since the functional requirement is unclear, it's hard to give you a well suited code example of the correct approach.